# Access and remove dynamically created element

Tags: javascript, html, dynamically-generated

I've used a for loop to create a bunch of images with unique ids. They look something like this:

```
<img src="image.jpg" id="110021002" />
<img src="image.jpg" id="110021003" />
<img src="image.jpg" id="110031002" />
...
```

Later on in the code I want to select one of the images by ID and remove it. I tried the following:

```
var removeId = '110021002';
var img = document.getElementById(removeId);
img.parentNode.removeChild(img);
```

But I get the following error:

```
Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null
```

Not quite sure what's going on here. Is it because the images were created dynamically?

Comment: How are you adding the image to the document? You have said that you are adding it dynamically, but gave no example.

Comment: That error means that, at that point in time, `img` is `null`.  Through in a `console.log` to see that.  The `id` that you are trying to remove must not match your images.

Comment: `img` is `null`. the `<img>` is not there. How do you instantiate the images? When do you invoke the "removal code"? Please update your question to be more contextual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works perfect: http://jsbin.com/zexoweyu/3/edit **for the first time you remove an element**, obvisouly on the second attempt the element is not there and it will throw the given error.

On the fiddle:

- Click once, works
- Click again, fails because the element with that ID is no longer there.

And yes, ids can start with numbers.

```
**Attribute ID** Specifies a unique id for the element. Naming rules:
Must contain at least one character
Must not contain any space characters
In HTML, all values are case-insensitive
```

Comment: Thanks but this example does not involve dynamically creating the images first, which I suspect may be the cause of the problem.

Comment: listen, the problem you raised it due to this reason, if you have another issue, that's not the question you posed. My answer addresses this very particular problem.

Comment: I don't understand. The issue isn't that I'm trying to remove the element more than once. Also, I did clearly indicate in my question that I was concerned about the dynamic element creation being the issue..

Comment: you do not provide enough context then, if you provide the code generating the `img` tags we might be able to help, so far your code doesn't have anything wrong on the removal function.

Comment: Just done a bit more testing and it turns out my code may have been attempting to remove the element more than once after all. Thanks for your answer that made me check this.

Comment: just to point out that your code do work with dynamic created elements as seen [here](http://jsbin.com/zexoweyu/4/edit)

Answer (score -1):

You can't have IDs that [start with a number](http://css-tricks.com/ids-cannot-start-with-a-number/). Try prefixing them with a letter.

Comment: Wow I somehow overlooked that! Thanks.

Comment: Yes HTML5 allows IDs to be numbers

Comment: You could with HTML 4 too. You just couldn't get them using document.getElementById(). The link page even shows an example of how to use the class selector with a numeric starting id.